# Need to close Word documents on Mac Air..I can see no red dot, green dot or yellow dot

Tags: ms-office

When I go to full screen on a Word for Mac document, the dots (red, yellow, green) disappear, and I can't get them back.  Therefore, I am not able to close a document.  Can someone tell me how to reduce the page size on a Word for Mac document so I can see the dots?  I've poked around for hours and found nothing online or in the help section.  Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Word is in Full Screen mode. Simply hover your mouse at the top of the window, and the Menu bar will drop down. On the right hand side is a blue double-headed arrow. Click it, and the screen will return to a window.  (you can save the document by simply using the menu when it drops down from your mouse hover, if you wish to remain in full screen mode...oh and CMD-S is your friend (save))

Or, you can just hit ESC.

Answer (score 1):

I addition to @cmason's correct answer, you may find it advantageous to review Apple Support's ["Mac Basics - Tour the Mac Interface."](https://www.apple.com/support/macbasics/tour/)

More specifically regarding full screen apps, you will find further reading here: [OS X Yosemite: Take apps full screen.](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18744?locale=en_US)

Excerpt:

> Return to standard view: Move the pointer to the top-left corner of
> the screen, then click the green full-screen button again, or press
> <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Command (⌘)</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>.

One more:

> ### OS X Yosemite: Window basics
>
> Switch to full screen In many apps, including Calendar and Mail, you
> can expand the window to fill your entire screen.
>
> Click the green full-screen button in the top-left corner of an app
> window.
>
> Button for entering full screen Return to standard view by **moving the
> pointer to the top-left corner of the screen**, then clicking the green
> full-screen button again.

Answer (score 0):

The same as on any Mac OS since the dawn of time...

<kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>W</kbd>  will close the window.

It's well worth learning the basics - though this list is pretty heavy & you may never remember them all...

## [Mac keyboard shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/HT201236)